# The function setState is not defined. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the colour of my checkbox(actually custom checkbox) for this I have written the code below , while I press the icon the `onPressed()` method is called but the colour of the icon doesn't change at all.

My widgets `setState()` is un-recognized. I have included `import package:flutter/material.dart`

here's the code

```
Widget _choice() {
var isPressed = false;
return Container(
height: 90,
width: 160,
color: Color(0xFFe6e9ed),
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.check_circle,
          size: 25,
            color:(isPressed) ? Color(0xff007397) : Color(0xff9A9A9A)
        ),
      onPressed: (){
        setState((){ // <--  this setState is un-recognizable by flutter ide
          if(isPressed){ print("checkbox pressed");
          isPressed = false;
          } else {
            isPressed = true;
          }
        });
      },
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(-0.8, 0),
      child: Text("Category choice 1"),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.phonelink,
        size: 40,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),);}
```

Comment: I believe you are not using StatefulWdiget.

Comment: Make _choice a stateful widget (have it extend StatefulWidget) instead of just a method in order to use setState

Comment: i have extended my class with StatefulWidget already, this is the widget i created outside the class and calling it inside the build widget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

> A widget that has mutable state.
>
> State is information that (1) can be read synchronously when the widget is built and (2) might change during the lifetime of the widget. It is the responsibility of the widget implementer to ensure that the State is promptly notified when such state changes, using State.setState.
> For example

```
class MyDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDemoState createState() => _MyDemoState();
}

class _MyDemoState extends State<MyDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: IconButton(icon: null, onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          //Do your stuff
        });
      }),
    );
  }
// every method which changes state should exist within class only
  Widget _check(){
    return IconButton(icon: null, onPressed: (){
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I have written the same code as above, but instead of returning a container i returned a scaffold where rows / columns are returning by calling the widgets that are defined outside the class. ie

Comment: any method which changes `state` should exist within _MyDemoState! see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much Ravinder Kumar, i inserted all my widgets before the last curly brace and it worked , thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a stateful widget to use `setState`.
`setState` is used to change the state of the widget.
You can go through
[Stateless & Stateful Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)
documentation to read in-deapth about this.