# Why is my star system isnt work in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

This is my code for making the star turn yellow and grey consistently, but it didn't work. Why?

```
Widget placeButton(BuildContext context, String name, String image, String id) {
      var color;
      var isClicked = true;
      return Column(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(130.0, 0.0, 130.00, 0.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              width: 400,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, id);
                },
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 0),
                      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(name),
                          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Manrope', fontSize: 18)),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Image.network(
                      image,
                      height: 250,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 40,
          width: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text(
              "Rating:",
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Klasik'),
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              splashRadius: 20,
              icon: Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined, color: color),
              
              onPressed: () {
                if (isClicked) {
                  color = Colors.grey;
                  isClicked = !isClicked;
                } else {
                  color = Colors.yellow;
                  isClicked = !isClicked;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]);
    }
```

P/S: Feel free to ask me about the code below. I tried setState but it didn't work. It returns error like this:
The function 'setState' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'setState', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'setState'.

Comment: Show full widget code not only the placebutton code. Without it I will say that setState isn't working for you because your widget is not a StatefulWidget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The function setState is not defined. Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101356/the-function-setstate-is-not-defined-flutter)

Comment: no, i can't make it to work

Comment: Show full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is only available within the scope of a `StatefulWidget`. You might want change the `StatelessWidget` to a stateful one. Once that's done, you'll need to introduce the variables `color` and `isClicked` outside of the `build` method or any other method that's called from `build` (such as `placeButton` in this example). Then you can call `setState` and change those values.

Here's a simplified example

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  // Define these outside of your build method
  Color color = Colors.grey;
  bool isClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: placeButton(context, 'name', 'image', 'id')),
    );
  }

  Widget placeButton(
    BuildContext context,
    String name,
    String image,
    String id,
  ) {
    // rest of your function...
    onPressed: () {
      // Use setState to change the values
      setState(() {
        if (isClicked) {
          color = Colors.grey;
          isClicked = !isClicked;
        } else {
          color = Colors.yellow;
          isClicked = !isClicked;
        }
      });
    },
  }
}
```

When using `setState`, Flutter will run the `build` function again and notice the values of `color` and `isClicked` have changed and use those new values to update the UI.